# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in ado.net

Tags: sql-server, object, reference, ado.net

I don't understand what the issue in this code is:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);

DataTable dtClass = ds.Tables[0];
int row = 0;

foreach (DataRow drClass in dtClass.Rows)
{
     classData[row].className = Convert.ToString(drClass.ItemArray[0].ToString());
    row++;
}
```

Comment: What is `classData`? Also use `drClass.Field<string>(0)` instead of `Convert.ToString(drClass.ItemArray[0].ToString());`

Comment: On **which line** does this error occur? Which object is NULL??